# KDevelop has no build menu

Tags: ubuntu, kdevelop

I have just installed KDevelop on my Ubuntu machine (KDevelop 3.9.95 on Ubuntu 9.10) with

sudo apt-get install kdevelop

I created a new project with the "Hello World" program in it, but there doesn't appear to be any way to compile anything. The manuals refer to the build menu but there isn't one, all all compile options on the other menus are greyed out.

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to open the Configure Launches window on the Run menu, then specify the Project Target (just write the name of your project). After this all build and debug options should be enabled

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The new version of kdevelop I downloaded this morning still doesn't have a build menu but your advice enabled me to get at least the build and execute buttons on the toolbar to work.